# Parsing date gives error in webapp

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am using the below function in my web app to compare two dates are equal or after or before.

```
public class DateComareClass{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {

        DateTimeComparator dateTimeComparator=DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat dftreg = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date currentDate = new Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
        Date SignUpDateCheck = (Date) dftreg.parse("2018-07-05");
        System.out.println(SignUpDateCheck + " is the SignUpDateCheck ");
        System.out.println(currentDate + " is the currentDate ");
        int retval=dateTimeComparator.compare(currentDate,SignUpDateCheck);
        System.out.println(retval);
        SignUpDateCheck = (Date) dftreg.parse("2018-07-13");

        System.out.println(SignUpDateCheck + " is the SignUpDateCheck ");
        System.out.println(currentDate + " is the currentDate ");
        retval=dateTimeComparator.compare(currentDate,SignUpDateCheck);
        System.out.println(retval);


    }
}
```

It prints

```
Thu Jul 05 00:00:00 2018 is the SignUpDateCheck  
Thu Jul 12 12:03:39 2018 is the currentDate
1
Fri Jul 13 00:00:00 2018 is the SignUpDateCheck  
Thu Jul 12 12:03:39 2018 is the currentDate 
-1
```

But if I use the same logic in my webapp it seems to print always the retval as -1 whether it is after ,before and equal to the date .

My code snippet in webapp

```
String GenerateSignupDate=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
SignUpDateCheck= (Date) dftreg.parse(GenerateSignupDate);
System.out.println(SignUpDateCheck + " is the SignUpDateCheck ");
System.out.println(currentDateReg + " is the currentDateReg ");
//System.out.println(SignUpDateCheck.before(currentDateReg) + " is the answer ");
retval=dateTimeComparator.compare(currentDate,SignUpDateCheck);
System.out.println(retval + " is the retval ");
```

But the Signup, current dates are printed correctly. It only prints the retval incorrectly.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Could you please show the results of the `System.out.println` calls in your webapp? Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Also, please copy/paste the webapp code snippet instead of typing it in... it looks like there's a `Date` missing before `SignUpDateCheck= (Date) dftreg...` As well, `currentDateReg` is not declared.  There's enough difference between the MCVE (thanks for doing that) and what you claim is running in the webapp that we cannot be sure what is happening.  Please post the complete _actual_ code from the webApp, and also the _actual_ output you get, with the commented `println` uncommented.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior after taking your "web app" snippet and making it executable by fixing the errors and providing the missing declaration.  Clearly something is different in your webapp and it does not match the [MCVE[ you posted.

Comment: Since you are already using Joda-Time, the library that I think was meant to replace the old and poorly designed classes `Date`, `Calendar` and (partly, at least) `SimpleDateFormat`, I am wondering why you are also using those old classes? A third option, of course, would be to move on to [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), since Joda-Time is now in maintenance mode.